# How to ensure java clients continue "working" in case whole hazelcast cluster is down

Tags: java, hibernate, hazelcast, failover, failovercluster

We are currently preparing hazelcast for going live in the next weeks. There is still one bigger issue left, that troubles our OPs department and could be a possible show stopper in case we cannot fix it.

Since we are maintaining a high availability payment application, we have to survive in case the cluster ist not available. Reasons could be:

1. Someone messed up the hazelcast configuration and a map on the cluster increases until we have OOM (had this on the test system).
2. There is some issue with the network cards/hardware that temporary breaks the connection to the cluster
3. OPs guys reconfigured the firewall and accidentaly blocked some ports that are necessary, whatosoever.
4. Whatever else

I spent some time on finding good existing solution, but the only solution so far was to increase the number of backup servers, which of course does not solve the case.

During my current tests the application completely stopped working because after certain retries the clients disconnect from the cluster and the hibernate 2nd level cache is no longer working. Since we are using hazelcast throughout the whole ecosystem this would kill 40 java clients almost instantly.

Thus I wonder how we could achieve that the applications are still working in a of course slower manner when the cluster is down. Our current approach is to switch over to ehcache local cache but I think there should be hazelcast solution for that problem as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would use a [LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) and set the [cacheRegionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setCacheRegionFactory-org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory-) to a Spring Bean that can delegate a call to either Hazelcast or a [NoCachingRegionFactory](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cache/internal/NoCachingRegionFactory.html), if the Hazelcast server is down.

This is desirable, since Hibernate assumes the Cache implementation is always available, so you need to provide your own CacheRegion proxy that can decide the cache region routing at runtime.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking in the wrong direction but afaik. RegionFactory is only there to build the different regions (Entity, Collection, QueryResults, Timestmaps) and hibernate uses it on startup and shutdown of the SessionFactoryImpl. After the regions have been build, hibernate iterates over the regions and grabs the region access strategies.

Comment: Meaning, just replacing the region wouldn't solve the problem since hibernate would still use the "wrong" access strategies internally to access the different regions. On our current approach we build up a wrapper which uses both the ehcache and hazelcast regions and switches over if the cluster is down but this is quite dirty and I'd really like to go with hazelcast only

Comment: I don't think it's dirty. Any other implementation can fail too. You can run out of memory or disk space on your cache provider and the exception will be propagated to your application cod. So a fallback approach is the best approach for high availability.

Comment: @u6f6o I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this. Can you share a sample code please.

Comment: Also i dont think LocalSessionFactoryBean works with spring dataJPA as that requires EntityManagerFactory...

Comment: @Art: We went for a different approach at the end. Instead of sharing the data across the whole cluster, we maintained a local cache that was invalidated by events triggered by Hibernate and Hazelcast. You can think of it as a ConcurrentHashMap underneath with typical LRU and LFU mechanics and events on top that evicted certain entries in the map. This bears some risk of inconsistency as you might miss certain events/invalidations but the data on the other hand was almost never changing so we could cope with that. Also the operation mode was peer-to-peer instead of master slave.

Comment: Which means you went with hazelcastLocalRegion ? Were you not able to achieve what you asked in the question.?